# How to enable chinese input method for qt5 app in docker

Tags: qt, docker, cjk

I have built a qt5 program in ubuntu docker, but i can't change input method as sougo for input chinese characters. My docker is support chinese characters because i can copy chinese characters to qt app gui. Is there any hints should i to resolve this problem?